# Undo shortcut on JupyterLab Desktop

Tags: jupyter-notebook, keyboard-shortcuts, jupyter-lab

I'm new to using JupyterLab Desktop for Windows, so I apologize if my question seems basic. I'm encountering a problem with the "Ctrl + Z" feature. Specifically, when I'm typing code in a cell of a notebook and I want to undo my last action, pressing "Ctrl + Z" closes the entire notebook instead. It is only a shortcut problem since the "Undo" button works well.

Note: I'm using a French keyboard.

When I attempted to configure the shortcuts in the settings, I noticed that the letters were being recognized, but not the symbols like ^ and %. I don't have any issues when typing code.

I've never encountered this problem in Spyder or other applications. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for mentioning you thought it may be related to using French keyboard because it helped [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77969356/8508004).