# Ctrl Z closing the file instead of undo in jupyterlab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I've downloaded to jupyterlab 4.10-1 in a new laptop but the ctrl z function tries to close the file instead of doing the Undo function, it still works if I do edit-> Undo but not with the shortcut.

All the other shortcut seems to work.

Do you have any idea of how to fix that?

Comment: Any chance you have a French keyboard? It sounds sort of like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77300919/8508004) but the OP there was using JupyterLab Desktop & sadly no answer there yet.

Comment: Yes I'm using a french keyboard, I tried to change the shortcut but just clicking on Ctrl and Z is closing the settings page, when I put ^N instead of ^Z, it works as intended

Comment: Maybe choose to add on first then and then see if you can delete the original by right-clicking after you have at least one new one?

Comment: In fact Ctrl N works as intended for "Ctrl Z" but Ctrl Z still close my current file in jupyterlab, I thought that it could be because Z is at the place of W "Azerty" instead of "Qwerty" but Ctrl w just close entirely the jupyterlab app without asking to save

Comment: I'm lost now. Did my answer at least somewhat guide you to how to fix it yet or not? And if it did, does my answer need to some adjustment to match what you needed to do?

Comment: Your answer allow me to use multiple combination of Ctrl+ key other than Z to do « Undo ». However, I m really used to Ctrl Z and I can’t figure out why this shirtcut close the active page

Answer (score 1):

One way you can 'fix' it is by making the shortcut anything you want. Under '`Settings`' in the tool ribbon across the top of JupyterLab, choose '`Settings Editor`' (probably at the bottom of the listing under that menu item).
Then from that list choose '`Keyboard Shortcuts`'. Cick on the magnifying glass in the top of the Keyboard Shortcust panel and enter `undo`. You should see one listing that has under 'Category' `editmenu` and under 'Command' `Undo`. Right-click on the 'Shortcut' entry for that one and choose '`Edit`' from the dropdown. **Note that based on feedback from the OP you may want to choose '`Add`' and add another option instead of just editing the original.**
Change it to something your browser won't react to, which may take some trial and error or digging around in your browser's shortcuts.

Comment: Update: I disable the close on 'Ctrl W' in jupyterlab desktop parameters, now the file don't close but the shortcut 'Ctrl Z' is not working for Undo and just does nothing.

When I try to rebind the shortcut only the (^) (Ctrl) is taken, looks like it can't take the ctrl and Z at the same time

Comment: When I click on the Notebook link (at the top right) the shortcut works as intended strangely

Comment: Chaning my keyboard to US in Windows does'nt change anything

Comment: "When I click on the Notebook link (at the top right) the shortcut works as intended". So is it opening it again in another window?

Comment: Yes, it opens in another window and on this new page I have a link at the same spot to go back to jupyterlab, again in a new window. Both in the Jupyterlab and Jupyter notebook window the Undo shortcut (ctrl z) works as intented

Comment: I's written JupyterLab (auto-D) on this window if that can help

Comment: I believe what you are describing by 'written JupyterLab (auto-D)' is referring to a different workspace of the same `.ipynb` file. This is interesting that it has traits different than in the workspace where the shortcuts didn't work if I am understanding correctly. You can see more about [workspaces here](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/directories.html#jupyterlab-workspaces-directory). Because the profiles will be different, I wonder if you have a bad profile somewhere? I know this sounds weird but it could at least be pointing towards understanding this all.

Comment: You understood perfectly correctly.

What is interesting is that the results of my Ctrl Z command depends of what I put in:
Settings->advanced-> Ctrl+W behavior ("Close, tab", "Close session", "Warn and close session" and "Do not close") while my Ctrl+W command still close my Jupyterlab session

Is there a not too difficult  way to modify the Ctrl+W behavior so that I can change the "Do not close "to "Undo" and maybe solve the issue?




         I ask that because there is no settings "hamburger/3 horizontal lines" in the auto-D workspace so maybe the issue comes from here